# How to add service reference from several computers

Tags: c#, wcf

[This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649818.aspx) article describe hot to Host WCF in a Windows Service Using TCP
After the service installed on the machine i build simple `Console Application Project` and `Add Service Reference`.
until here it's all clear and works fine even from another computer on the same network.
My question is if i installed my service on several machines and each machine with different IP address of course how can i test my client application ?
do i need Several `Console Application Projects` and from each one `Add Service Reference` with different IP address (App.config) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on what you wish to accomplish. If it is the same service deployed to all the machines, then you can use the same service reference, in the sense that you will use the same generated contracts. What you will need to change is which of the machines to connect to, which you will change in the service client section of your app.config. As long as all the services use the same version of the contracts, you can then swap connect to whichever you like. You do need to specify one, however, not several. If you want to do load balancing, you will need to do that separately.

If the services that you deploy are not identical in contract, then you will need to add more service references, one for each variation in contract.

**EDIT:** Given that we want to set the client endpoint address at runtime, but assuming that we have generated a client proxy (`MyServiceClient`) with the service reference tool:

1. Create the endpoint address using your input
2. Get a client to that address
3. Make your calls, and make sure to close your client afterwards or, preferrably, wrap in an `using`

A full example, with proper handling of the client:

```
void MakeCall(Uri serviceEndpoint) {
    var address = new EndpointAddress(serviceEndpoint);
    using(var client = new MyServiceClient(address)) {
        client.MakeCallToSomeServiceFunction();
    }
}
```

You can then call this with something like `MakeCall(new Uri("http://mymachine:8080"))`, or get the input from some UI.

Comment: All my services on the machines is the same, the only different is inside app.config  (h t t p://MachineIpAddress:8000/) - how can i do this ?

Comment: Ok, so all services are alike. Why do you want to have several of them? Do you want to call all of them, or any single one?

Comment: I want to call single, i am open specific file end edit this file, i want combo box and from this control choose my machine

Comment: In that case, just change the app.config value to whatever machine you want to call. If you have it deployed on `http://machine-a:8080` and `http://machine-b:12345`, you can change what server you connect to by simply changing the address in the app.config file (in the address attribute on the endpoint element)

Comment: Ah. You want to change what endpoint you connect to using code? How will the code know what address to set on the endpoint?

Comment: I have Combobox and inside this combobox all my machines IP's, the user only need to choose the relevant machine

Comment: Added an example of how to set the address to some user input

Comment: This example replace the app.config file ?

Comment: The app.config values will not be used, exactly.

Comment: Yes. The steps were to describe why the code example looks like it does

Comment: I need to delete my app.config ?

Comment: No, you can (should) keep your app.config. It probably contains other things that you need.

Comment: What should i put instead of MyServiceClient ? currently i am sing in my code in ServiceReference1.MySampleWCFServiceClient service = new ServiceReference1.MySampleWCFServiceClient();